# How is the camera view moving with a mouse

Tags: workflow

I'm new to blender (literally been a few hours) and I'm following this tutorial but not having any luck with moving the camera view. In the [video](https://youtu.be/VnFQdIRbd6U?t=60) the person says he right clicks to move the view, but when I try it in blender (version 2.92.0) I just get a menu pop up. How do I move the view?

[image: Moving with right click causes menu to pop up]

Comment: mmh actually you don't need to right click (or left click) on the camera to move it the way he does, you need to open the N panel (on the right of the 3D view) > View tab > View > View Lock > activate Camera to View. From now on you can move the camera the same way you navigate in the 3D view

Comment: Thanks. Attempting to follow your instructions but I don't see the options you mentioned. I think I've navigated to a similar option but now need to read up on this.